# I try to get a list of new youtube video posted today by email

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to get by email a liste a new Youtube vidéo from my subscription :

```
module {
  function sendDailyEmail() {
    // Get the list of your YouTube subscriptions.
    var subscriptions = YouTube.subscriptions.list({
      part: "snippet"
    });

    // Get the list of new videos from your subscriptions.
    var newVideos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < subscriptions.items.length; i++) {
      var subscription = subscriptions.items[i];
      var newVideosForSubscription = YouTube.videos.list({
        part: "snippet",
        channelId: subscription.id,
        publishedAfter: new Date().toISOString()
      });
      newVideosForSubscription.items.forEach(function(video) {
        newVideos.push(video);
      });
    }

    // Create the email body.
    var body = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < newVideos.length; i++) {
      body += "<h3>" + newVideos[i].snippet.title + "</h3>";
      body += newVideos[i].snippet.description + "<br>";
      body += newVideos[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url + "<br>";
    }

    // Send the email.
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "your@email.com",
      subject: "Your daily YouTube update",
      body: body
    });
  }
}
```

I get an error : Erreur de syntaxe : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (ligne : 1, file : Code.gs)

Thanks for your help

I launch the Script but i get the error : Erreur de syntaxe : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (ligne : 1, fichier : Code.gs)

Comment: It looks like it doesn't recognize the module.  Neither do I.

Comment: If you just remove that first line `module {` and the final curly brace, it should run (at least I don't notice any other issues in the body of the code).